# Using facebook ads sdk in symfony

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, facebook-ads-api

I downloaded facebook ads sdk using composer. Everything worked fine. Now I want to add this sdk to my existing symfony project. I copied all content to `/lib/vendor`. After that I am trying to use api here:

```
if (is_null($access_token) || is_null($app_id) || is_null($app_secret)) {
      throw new \Exception(
        'You must set your access token, app id and app secret before executing'
      );
    }
    else
    {
        echo "fine.";
    }
    if (is_null($account_id)) {
      throw new \Exception(
        'You must set your account id before executing');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "fine.";
    }
// define('SDK_DIR','/var/www/html'); // Path to the SDK directory
// $loader = include '/vendor/autoload.php';
// $this->loader->registerNamespace('FacebookAds',sfConfig::get('sf_lib_dir') . '/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds');
// use FacebookAds\Api;

Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
```

I am getting error: `Fatal error: Class 'Api' not found in`

How can I add this sdk to symfony.

Comment: Is the code right above Api:init() commented out in your script? You'll need it to be executed in order for it to register the PHP autoloader and import the FacebookAds\Api for use

Comment: that is not working. Please help me with an uncommented example.